# How do I run a modulo conditional using one list on another list in python

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, conditional-statements, modulo

I've only been using python for about 2 weeks and need some help. I am trying to use the mod (%) function between two lists of varying sizes.

```
n = 23 #user input, starting point for the code
listp = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
listr = list(range((n-1)**2, n**2+1, 2))
listb = list(listr)  #I need to remove items from listr but if i do, it 
                     #crashes so I decided to copy it to listb in order to manipulate it

for k in listr:
    for i in listp[1:]:
        if k%i == 0:
            if k in listb:
                listb.remove(k)
```

This works but it's slow, I'd like to manipulate listr directly and I can individually:

```
listr = [k for k in listr if i%listp[1] !=0]
listr = [k for k in listr if i%listp[2] !=0]
```

Bottom line is that I'd like to use the % function on each k element in listr using every i element in listp and only keep those elements in listr that are !=0; I've tried using numpy and an array but that's not helping either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop from the moment you have found `any` such value. So replace:

```
for k in listr:
    for i in listp[1:]:
        if k%i == 0:
            if k in listb:
                listb.remove(k)
```

With:

```
for k in listr:
    if any(k%i == 0 for i in listp[1:]):
        listb.remove(k)
```

which will already yield some speedup. But `list.remove` is slow, it works in *O(n)*. So now we can turn this into list comprehension:

```
listr = [k for k in listr if not any(k%i == 0 for i in listp[1:])]
```

So we add the number to the new `listr` list, if no such modulo condition holds. A `not any(p(x) for x in X)` can be rewritten to `all(not p(x) for x in X)`, so we can apply this here:

```
listr = [k for k in listr if all(k%i != 0 for i in listp[1:])]
```

Furthermore we can also save some cycles, by making a list `listp1`:

```
listp1 = listp[1:]
listr = [k for k in listr if all(k%i != 0 for i in listp1)]
```

since now we only construct a new list once. Finally we can remove the `!= 0` since the truthiness of an integer is `True` if and only if the value is not equal to zero:

```
listp1 = listp[1:]
listr = [k for k in listr if all(k%i for i in listp1)]
```

Note that there are faster approaches than the *Sieve of Eratosthenes*.

Comment: When constructing the new list, is there any reason `listr` cannot be used instead of `listb` in the list comprehension?

Comment: Wow, thanks! I've digested the first part and it reduced the run time almost in half! I'll keep plugging away.

Comment: Also, I realized that I was stuck on order of ops because I wanted to reduce listr; but once I started the for loop with listp, I got what I wanted:

listr = [k for k in listr if i%listp[1] !=0]
listr = [k for k in listr if i%listp[2] !=0] 

instead I wrote:

for i in listp:
    listr = [k for k in listr if k%i !=0]

Comment: Okay, again wow, I used the second recommendation and since I was using the coding above in two areas of my code, the run time went from just over two minutes to 6 sec. BTW do you have a post or link on the faster approaches than the Sieve of Eratosthenes?

Comment: @spaceexplorer: see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes#Complexity).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, I'll check it out, I also got back to digesting the rest of the code and it sped things up even more, thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

For faster operations you can try using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html), it uses numpy under the hood and "pushes the work down to C level". Look at [arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

Then create a function to do the work you want and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) it to all entries of your panda data structure and capture it: something like

final _list = pandas_struct.apply(function)

Some sample you could play with follow:
How fast is acceptable?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n=23
first = np.array([2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13])
second = np.arange((n-1)**2, n**2+1, 2)
pand_second=pd.Series(second)

def modme(num,div):
    if num % div  == 0:
        return num,'mod ok by',div

[9]: pand_second.apply(modme, args=(3,))
Out[9]: 
0                    None
1     (486, mod ok by, 3)
2                    None
3                    None
4     (492, mod ok by, 3)
5                    None
6                    None
7     (498, mod ok by, 3)
8                    None
9                    None
10    (504, mod ok by, 3)
11                   None
12                   None
13    (510, mod ok by, 3)
14                   None
15                   None
16    (516, mod ok by, 3)
17                   None
18                   None
19    (522, mod ok by, 3)
20                   None
21                   None
22    (528, mod ok by, 3)
dtype: object


%timeit pand_second.apply(modme, args=(3,))
81.3 µs ± 201 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Or not use pandas at all :):

```
import numpy as np

n=23
first = np.array([2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13])
second = np.arange((n-1)**2, n**2+1, 2)

In [11]: [ second[ second % x == 0 ] for x in first ]
Out[11]: 
[array([484, 486, 488, 490, 492, 494, 496, 498, 500, 502, 504, 506, 508,
        510, 512, 514, 516, 518, 520, 522, 524, 526, 528]),
 array([486, 492, 498, 504, 510, 516, 522, 528]),
 array([490, 500, 510, 520]),
 array([490, 504, 518]),
 array([484, 506, 528]),
 array([494, 520])]


%timeit [ second[ second % x == 0 ] for x in first ]
15.6 µs ± 25.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: prove through code not by generalizations. apply is not vectorized; so will be slow.

Comment: Didn't dv, but even the fastest supercomputer on earth with extensive parallelisation, will eventually be outperformed by a smartphone that uses an algorithm with a lower time complexity.

Comment: @sharatc re-read the sentences. I never said apply is vectorized. Where is you're code to show that it will be 'slow' :P

Comment: I've heard of pandas too, I just got numpy to load yesterday, is pandas similar in difficulty to load?

Comment: @spaceexplorer - pandas was easy for me to load - perhaps enter a new question? - I'd be happy to try to help you. Pandas is great!

Comment: @jouell, thanks! I'm basically trying to get it to run as fast as possible; the n = 23 is a benign example but I wanted to start simple, eventually I'd like n to be any number a user chooses so speed is definitely a must. I'll check pandas for sure and I'll come back to the code you gave, thanks for taking the time! I'm having fun coding in python (I have a java, matlab and fortran background as well as scientific background).